# Welder display flickering

Tags: metal, welding

Just bought a 2nd hand welder. Boc smootharc 185 tig. After stick welding for a while (haven't got argon to tig yet) I go to shut off the unit and the display flashes a few times before it dies off. Is this a normal thing or is something on its way out?

Comment: Customer Service- BOC Australia: 131 262, contact@boc.com ||| BOC New Zealand: 0800 111 333, customer.servicenz@boc.com. You should drop them a line. Also, [here's the manual](http://www.boc.com.au/wcsstore/AU_BOC_Industrial_Store/pdf/product/en_AU/BOC185ACDC-manual.pdf) (I think).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's best handled by contacting the vendor for product specific support.

Answer (score 2):

So, the LCD current meter functions properly until you turn the unit off, upon which it flashes a few times before going completely dark?

That's no big deal. There's something odd about how the various power supply capacitors store and discharge their energy as the unit is shut off, but that's just iffy design, not indications of a real problem.